# Rails: NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was setting up authorization using the code below and got an error. I'm using devise

```
undefined method `is_admin?' for #<User:0x007f803734ba48>
```

I've already setup the admin user in the console but I'm having issues testing out users trying to log in.

```
    RailsAdmin.config do |config|
      config.authorize_with do
        redirect_to main_app.root_path unless warden.user.is_admin?
      end
    end
```

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authorization

Comment: Please post the `user.rb`. You should be having `is_admin?` in your `users` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:
   Include a boolean field in your users table and name it admin

Then use this:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.admin == true
  end
end
```

Comment: Your error results due to lack of is_admin method. You can define it in your user.rb file in oder to check whether current user is admin. i.e def return self.admin? end

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Warden? On the same page I've found some [custom authorization](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Customized-authorization). Have you tried that?

Comment: @JamesRocky please remember to click the green check-mark to mark this answer as the correct one, if it solved your problem.